# Qt - Saving a QString path to QSettings in regisrty

Tags: c++, qt, registry, qstring, qsettings

I have an application and the user can change the default folder for saving files.

The folder in which the user saves the files: `QString SaveImagesDirectory;`

I want that when the user quits the application, the data in SaveImagesDirectory will be saved in the registry.

I tried the following code:

```
QSettings settings(ORG_NAME, APP_NAME);
settings.setValue("LastGuiValue/LastSaveImagesDirectory",SaveImagesDirectory);
```

The problem is that when I refreshed the registry, there was no value in LastSaveImagesDirectory.

Therefore when I tried to read using the following code:

```
SaveImagesDirectory=settings->value("LastGuiValue/LastSaveImagesDirectory",QDir::currentPath()).value<QString>();
```

The variable SaveImagesDirectory got only the `QDir::currentPath()`. I looked at the registry and indeed the `LastSaveImagesDirectory` was with no value.

Comment: Please call `sync()` method and than check the result of `status()` function of QSettings. Maybe you have not write rights to registry for example.

Comment: Hi Axilles, Thank you for your reply. I can write to registry for integer values. What needs to be done to save a qstring ? Please help me !

Comment: @EVH761 So what does `status()` function return? if it return `NoError` value, than you should be able to store all QVariant-supported values in registry - QString is among them.

Comment: What are your ORG_NAME and APP_NAME? May be they contain some non-latin1 characters?

Comment: Where did you put the code with setValue ? (For example, as the class destructor is not always called when the application quit, you might have to put it elsewhere).

Answer (score 1):

Good morning,

you could verify if the system is capable of writing to the registry by implementing a simple test program like this one:

```
// Registry Write Test Programm

#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QMessageBox>
#include <QtCore/QSettings>
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtCore/QVariant>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  QApplication *app   = new QApplication( argc, argv );
  QSettings settings( QLatin1String( "D-Soft" ), QLatin1String( "RegistryTest" ) );

  QString hello = settings.value( "LastGuiValue/LastSaveImagesDirectory" ).toString();
  QMessageBox::information( NULL, QLatin1String( "Info" ),
    QString( QLatin1String( "From Settings: %1" ) ).arg( hello ) );

  if( hello.isEmpty() )
    hello = QLatin1String( "Oh my!" );

  settings.setValue( "LastGuiValue/LastSaveImagesDirectory", hello );

  delete app;
  app = NULL;

  return 0;
}
```

Without the need for elevated permissions your program should be able to write into the HKLM_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE hive. This program should prove if it does. If it works you should check your code or post it, otherwise there is a deeper problem at hand.